# How to handle dynamic json in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

```
    {
       "status": "error",
        "msg": "Please fill all the fields",
       "error": {
             "device_token": [
                     "The device token field is required.",
            ]
             "mobile_number": [
                     "The mobile number field is required."
            ]
        }
    }
```

Here is my json response .How can i handle my error as the error object  is dynamic

Comment: The json you sent is invalid do you mean either device_token or mobile_numer will be present, or is a comma missing between them?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your JSON content in a variable and access your data as following.
**Also, don't forget the comma "," after the "device_token" key**

```
var res = {
  "status": "error",
  "msg": "Please fill all the fields",
  "error": {
    "device_token": [
      "The device token field is required."
    ],
    "mobile_number": [
      "The mobile number field is required."
    ]
  }
};

var deviceToken = (res["error"] as Map)["device_token"].first;
var mobileNumber = (res["error"] as Map)["mobile_number"].first;

print(deviceToken);
print(mobileNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading [JSON and Serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) in the Flutter docs.

Answer (score 0):

I use [json_seializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable). It is a good way to solve this problem.
Just to mark your models with decorators and generate each method automatically. BTW, this is recommended on [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).
And also it is really important to add types to your variables and use the Dart compiler's power